# Save shapefile data to single GDB instead of multiple GDBs

Tags: python, arcgis-pro

I want to modify this code so it doesn't create a GDB for each folder found. I want to add them to the map but save into a single GDB.

This worked well, but it's creating a GDB inside each folder it's searching for, I'm trying to merge all the shapefiles that look like well165s and well165b into a single GDB. Each shapefile is contained in the folder well165 and there are 249 of them.

```
import os
workspace = r"D:\USA\Wells_by_state\WELL_DATA\TX_Wells"
folders = [x[0] for x in os.walk(workspace)]
for folder in folders:
    print("Checking" + folder +"for shapefiles.")
    #set Workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    #list shaepfiles
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
    #check whether any shapefiles are present
    if len(fcs)>0:
        print("Shapefiles found! Creating a file gdb.")
        gdb_name = "gdb" + folder.split("\\")[-1]+".gdb"
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(folder, gdb_name)
        #for each shapefile, convert to file gdb format
        for fc in fcs:
            print("Converting"+fc+"to file gdb.format.")
            output_path = os.path.join(folder,gdb_name)
            out_name = arcpy.Describe(fc).basename
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc,output_path,out_name)
```

Comment: I suggest using [Walk - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) and not relying on those older ArcPy List functions that rely on changing the workspace.

Comment: Your current approach does not risk data sets with the same name in different folders clobbering each other.  Do all the shape files have different names?  If so, how do you want to handle moving feature classes with same name into one FGDB?

Comment: You could move arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(folder, gdb_name) outside the loop but beware: you could encounter the same dataset name in different folders, you'll need to check the name doesn't already exist in the GDB before you import then either modify the target dataset name to be unique. If overwrite is False and you have are trying to create a duplicate the script will terminate with an error, if overwrite is True then your script will happily overwrite previous instances *without warning*, neither is a good situation.

Comment: Another way to avoid feature class name clobbering would be to make `out_name` equal to some amalgamation of the folder name and the feature class name (eg, joined by "_", with spaces removed, etc).  (Assuming the folder names are unique, of course - which may not be the case if they are nested.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two changes:

Firstly, replace `arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(folder, gdb_name)` with `arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, gdb_name)` and move it outside of the first loop (before the loop).  (Note the change from `folder` to `wokspace` for the location of the fGDB).  This will create one single fGDB at the top level of your workspace folder, instead of one in each sub-folder.  This effectively answers your actual question.

But, it creates the potential for problems if there are shapefiles within the various folders that have the same name.  If this is the case, then each subsequent feature class (of the same name) would clobber (replace) the previous one(s) that was/were created, and those previous feature classes would be lost.  So...

Secondly, change `out_name` to include the sub-folder name (or path?) as well as the shapefile name, so that the output feature class will always have a unique name.  To do this you also have to account for the possibility of the folder (and shapefile) having characters in their names that are not permitted in feature class names in a fGDB.  In particular, space characters are the most common.  One way of doing this might be:

`out_name = "{}_{}".format(os.path.basename(folder), os.path.basename(fc)).replace(" ", "_")`

(This caters for spaces in the folder/shapefile names, but not for other non-alphanumeric characters.)

A couple of other minor changes would then be required to accommodate all this.  In particular, `out_path` is replaced with the `fgdb` path.

NB:  This is all completely untested!

```
import os
workspace = r"D:\USA\Wells_by_state\WELL_DATA\TX_Wells"
fgdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, gdb_name)
folders = [x[0] for x in os.walk(workspace)]
for folder in folders:
    print("Checking" + folder +"for shapefiles.")
    #set Workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    #list shaepfiles
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
    #check whether any shapefiles are present
    if len(fcs)>0:
        print("Shapefiles found! Creating a file gdb.")
        gdb_name = "gdb" + folder.split("\\")[-1]+".gdb"
        #for each shapefile, convert to file gdb format
        for fc in fcs:
            print("Converting"+fc+"to file gdb.format.")
            out_name = "{}_{}".format(os.path.basename(folder), os.path.basename(fc)).replace(" ", "_")
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, fgdb ,out_name)
```

NB:  This assumes that all the sub-folders have unique names (which is guaranteed if there is only one level of sub-folders).  If the folders are nested deeper than this, and may have non-unique names, then your `out_name` will have to be defined differently to accommodate this.

Comment: This is great! I will test it and each folder/shapefile does have a unique name. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This is the code that worked really well, it saved all these .shp files into a single database.

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = r"D:\USA\Wells_by_state\WELL_DATA\TX_Wells"
gdb_name = "TxWellsAll2.gdb"
fgdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, gdb_name)
folders = [x[0] for x in os.walk(workspace)]
for folder in folders:
    print("Checking" + folder + "for shapefiles.")
    # set Workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    # list shaepfiles
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
    # check whether any shapefiles are present
    if len(fcs)>0:
        for fc in fcs:
            # Convert from shape file to feature class and save to GDB
            print("Converting" + fc + "to file gdb.format.")
            out_name = "{}_{}".format(os.path.basename(folder), os.path.basename(fc)).replace(" ", "_")
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, fgdb, out_name)
```

Comment: Vince why did you take out that name? They provided the answer above.